# Understanding the workflow of form creation plugin

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, forms

I want to create a simple form creation plugin(that is specific for my CRM, that's why i need to create one). The idea is having a "add input" button which lets me chose the type of the input(text,phone,email,checkbox and etc), after I finish adding the input fields I click 'save' and it creates a shortcode as well.

I guess it should be some sort of custom post type because I want to keep a list of all the forms I created with the ability of editing them.

I need your guys help with the workflow. on understanding what I need to search for to create this.
I tried looking at plugins like Contact Form 7 but I didn't understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

The Worflow of a creation form plugin goes something like this:

```
(A) Data is submitted -> Data is placed into the WP database -> Data is handled -> Sending a notification via email and/or placement in the SalesForce database.
```

Whereas work flow need to go something like this:

```
(B) Data is submitted -> Data is handled -> notification is sent via email and/or placed in the SalesForce Database.
```

The key  is that data is never stored on the WP Database, only sent via email and/or stored on the SalesForce Database.